# How to Bind DoubleAnimation Enabled/Disabled

Tags: wpf

Please tell me how Can I solve my problem. The situatino is as follow:
I had a list box with image inside it, I would like some of the image to blinking, some not. I had the property "Emergeny" if it is true the image should blink, now the question is how can I bind it. I try to Bind to "Duartion" or "To" propperty but I receives an error. The code below is my image which is blinking.

```
<Image Height="32" Width="32" Source="{Binding Emergency, Converter={StaticResource boolToPath}}">
                    <Image.Style>
                    <Style>
                        <Style.Triggers>                                 
                            <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Image.Loaded">
                                <BeginStoryboard>
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Image.Opacity)" BeginTime="0:0:0" Duration="0:0:0.5"
                                                         From="1.0" To="0.0" RepeatBehavior="Forever" AutoReverse="True" />
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </BeginStoryboard>
                            </EventTrigger>
                        </Style.Triggers>
                    </Style>
                    </Image.Style>    
                    </Image>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of triggering on `Event.Loaded`, trigger on your property:

```
<Trigger Property="IsEmergency" Value="True">
    <BeginStoryboard .../>
</Trigger>
```

Comment: Thanks, thats also can help [link]http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742536.aspx